# How to load $_POST array with jQuery variables with/without using html form

Tags: php, html, jquery, post

I have run into some problems in $.ajax() and $.post() calls for sending some variables at interface-end to server-end PHP for processing.
Though this seems to be a trivial problem and reported heavily in forms but I tried with all the options from the last couple of days but met with no success.

My scenario is as follows:

I have a simple interface with a 4X4 grid drawn so that users can click on any position and a 2D coordinate value will recorded through a jquery function which is working fine. Now I need to send these two x-y variables to the PHP for storing in the DB with the click of a user button. I allow the user to click multiple times but have a submit button so that the final clicked values are only submitted.
I have all the work written in a file test.php as follows:

```
<?php
$x = $_POST['xval'];
$y = $_POST['yval'];
echo "X-Value......" . "$x";
echo "Y-Value......" . "$y";
// Code to store $x and $y in database
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var x=0;
var y=0;
$("#table").click(function(e1){
// Process x, y values from the grid..This part is working fine and tested also
})
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    //var $form = $(this);
    //var url_s = $form.attr('action');
    var data_s = {xval: 'x', yval: 'y'};
    //$.post("test.php", { xval:"x", yval: y });
      $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "test.php", data: {xval: 'x', yval: 'y'}});
})
});
</script>
<div class="form">
<form name="form100" id="form">
<input type="submit" name="SubmitOption" id="button" value="Next">
</form>
</div>
```

I am posting the values in the same page i.e. test.php, since I want to process the values in the top-part of the PHP-code, but I am not able to retrieve the $x, $y values in the PHP-end. 
The I tested to post with a form as follows:
    
    ">

After testing, I found that $_POST is only able to load the form variables with method="post" action=" but never works with $.post or $.ajax calls with jQuery variables.
I tried for a work around method by loading two text areas in the form from jQuery click function and then used the form POST with method="post" action=" which works since now the jQuery variables are transferred to the form variables.

How to perform a AJAX call ($.ajax or $.post) using only a form submit button and pass the jQuery variables to the server-PHP through the $_POST array since it seems that $_POST array gets loaded only with form variables from method="post" action=" and is not able to be invoked from $.post() and $.ajax() and pass the jQuery variables to the $_POST array.
Another question will be how to pass jQuery variables without a form in $_POST array using only a input type="button" click (tried with $("#button").click(function()....but POST not working with $.ajax and _POST array is empty) since technically I don't need a form as I do not have any form variables ?

Comment: Have you tried using just a normal button and binding to its .click event? I may be wrong, but your form might be getting submitted before the .ajax call is processed.

Comment: yeah, I would put that PHP below tha ajax call or, the proper way, in another different file, as well as the script in its own file.

Comment: @bfink: I tried with a normal button and binding with click() but not able to retrieve variables from $_POST array..So, the problem remains as how to pass jquery variables using $.ajax() or $.put() with a button click and access $_POST array from PHP ?

Comment: @elclanrs: Do you think that placing the PHP below the AJAX call will serve the purpose since AJAX call is initiated from the client-browser and the PHP processing is performed at the server end and in such a situation how can the sequence matters..Moreover, placing in a different file is an option, but what is the problem with the current scenario since it seems to be a quite regular process!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
$x = $_POST['xval'];
$y = $_POST['yval'];
echo "X-Value......$x";
echo "Y-Value......$y";
exit;
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {
            $('#button').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'test.php',
            data: {
            action   :'ADD' ,
            xval     :'x',
            yval     :'y'
         },
        success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
            } ,
        error : function(){
            alert('erroR');
           }
           })
         })  


$("#table").click(function(e1){
// Process x, y values from the grid..This part is working fine and tested also
})


   })
</script>
<div class="form">
<input type="submit" name="SubmitOption" id="button" value="Next">
</div>
```

and use firebug to catch possible jq-js syntax errors